# Misunderstanding phonegap-plugin-push version

Tags: cordova, templates, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I had some troubles using the phonegap-plugin-push.

First of all, I tried to insert it in my app using, in the config.xml file, this line:

```
<plugin spec="https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push.git" source="git" />
```

I think this is the better solution, BUT the plugin isn't included when I create the template of my app.

So, I tried to use this version

```
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="1.9.0">
    <param name="SENDER_ID" value="1111" /> 
</plugin>
```

In this way the plugin was correctly added in the template, but this version isn't correct for iOS, it works only for android.

So, using cordova cli tool, I added this plugin from command line, to check what will be written in confing.xml file. I got this:

```
<plugin spec="~1.10.5" name="phonegap-plugin-push"/>
```

In this way the plugin is included in the template, but I can't understand the version. Why there is "~" next to the version? Which version is this? Is it the last one? I know the last is 2.x, but this has a "1" as first number...

can you give me some help here?

**UPDATE**: Summarized all the steps here: https://programmingistheway.wordpress.com/2017/07/19/devextremephonegap-how-to-manage-push-notifications-with-fcm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna install the latest version (2.0.0-rc5) of phonegap push plugin  using Cordova CLI, try out this command:

> cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push@v2.0.0-rc5

Comment: Good idea, but... nope, it added the same row as before

Comment: @PieroAlberto I tried it in my local environment before answering and it works. Did you removed the plugin and tried re-adding? Initially i was able to simulate your scenario as you said but specific version during installed worked